# Initialize fields from an object when creating the object

Tags: custom-field, default-value

Is there any elegant way to create a new record with its default values in apex for all its fields??

Example:

1-I have the object `Car__c` with the fields

```
Color__c, Model__c, Brand__c, Type__c, Years__c
```

2-I create the record:

```
Car__c car = new Car__c(Color__c ="Red", Model__c = "Golf", Brand__c = "VW");
```

I want the field `Type__c` to be `""` (by default) and the field `Years__c` to be `0` (also by default)

I have tried to set the value by default in the Configuration of the field in **"General Options"** in the section default value with the formula editor but without success.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using new operator you can use [newSObject()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm) that will load the record with default values, and then you can change it wrt to your choice.

`public sObject newSObject(ID recordTypeId, Boolean loadDefaults)`

Thus your code will be:

```
Car__c car = new Car__c(Color__c ="Red", Model__c = "Golf", Brand__c = "VW");

Car__c car = (Car__c) Car__c.sObjectType.newSObject(null, true);
car.Color__c ='Red';
car.Model__c = 'Golf';
car.Brand__c ='VW';
```